# Is it possible to use <select> to choose the action for a search input

Tags: html, select, search, input

I'm trying to make a code where you can select the search engine and then search from there. Something like this:

```html
<form>
    <select>
        <option action="https://google.com/search" target="_blank">Google</option>
    </select>
  <input size="50" type="search" id="search" name="q">
</form>
```

I know that's not correct, but is it possible? If not, is there another way to do it?

Comment: You should try to get some more info related to HTML. Try https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp. that is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, Jquery

```js
$('button').click((e)=>{
 e.preventDefault();
 if($('select').val() === 'google'){
  let url = $('#search').val();
  console.log(`Text before: ${url}, selected: ${$('select').val()}`);
  url = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${url}&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8`;
  window.open(url, '_blank'); // open in new tab
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select>
        <option value="google">Google</option>
    </select>
    <input size="50" type="search" id="search" name="q"></input>
 <button>search</button>
</form>
```